Why browser set origin to null for sameorigindomain ie ASP.NET MVC web app has origin to null in chrome browser
My ASP.NET MVC web app is accessed by browser like Chrome. On login form submit, it has origin set to null by browser. This is identified as a security vulnerable by the webinspect tool.
Please advise what is the solution to this?

Hi, have you tried the solution given? Do you still need any assistance on this, let me know if you have any further concern.


My ASP.NET MVC web app is accessed by browser like Chrome. On login
form submit, it has origin set to null by browser. This is identified
as a security vulnerable by the webinspect tool.

According to the scenario and description, the null origin issue typically arises in situations where a web request is being made from a local file, a sandboxed iframe, or from an environment that does not have a defined origin. This can lead to security vulnerabilities, as some security tools might flag it because they can't verify the request's source.
It's hard to offer you any straightforward solution for that without seeing your configuration and why reqeust orgin has been set null.
However, couple of steps can be taken to deal with the situation.
First of all, If you're accessing your web app through a file:// URL instead of http:// or https://, the browser will set the origin to null.
On the other hands,  If your app is being loaded within an iframe with the sandbox attribute, the origin might be set to null.
Most importantly,  If the request is being made cross-origin and the server is not properly configured to handle CORS requests, the browser might set the origin to null.
Therefore, double chekc the above configuration if those are maintained accordingly. In addition, double check your CORS config as well.
If WebInspect or other security tools are flagging the null origin as a vulnerability, review their configuration and ensure they are appropriately set up to handle your application's context. Sometimes, these tools need specific configurations to correctly assess your application's security posture.
We also could set origin in request or request model using hidden property. Even we can use additional property within our request model.
You could do as following:
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string RequestOrigin { get; set; }
}

View:
Add additional property in view:
<input type="hidden" id="requestOrigin" name="RequestOrigin" />

Use Script:
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        document.getElementById('requestOrigin').value = window.location.origin;
    </script>
}

Controller:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
{

   var requestOrigin =  HttpContext.Request.Headers["Origin"].ToString();

    return View();
}

So now you could get request origin in both ways. If for unknows reason browser Origin get null but you still can get it from request model.
Output:




There is no cross domain request or file://. This is .Net  Framework MVC Web App that has this issue. The login page on submit request set origin to null.

Well, if the above steps you found correct, then check the WebInspect tool configuration, sometimes the tool trace security issues for minor reason as well. However, you could also set request origin in request header as well using request.Headers.Add("Origin", "https://your-origin.com");

Its also need to know how you are submitting login request.

It is .Net Framework MVC web form using HTML.BeginForm("Login","Account", FormMethod.Post, new {}). on subsequent navigation has origin se to null. since it is with in same origin , the browser set origin to null. The tool identify it as a security vulnerability

You can still set request origin and its same for asp.net core, upto  .NET8.

I have updated the answer, you could try that as well.

you mean adding the origin header would resolve the issue. where that has to be added

Within your login request form. See the answer for details.

Added this in request.Headers.Add("Origin", "https://your-origin.com") in custom httpModule but still on subsequent browser origin is set to null. Can your share your code. your sample set at client side for requestOrigin and not sure how it set to origin

I have already shared the details. Please include the code snippet of your login form, how you are sending login request and controller details.

Your code shows how to read origin in client side and server side right. Did you do anything specific to set the origin in the above code

As you have seen in the code I used window.location.origin to get the request origin authometiclly.

i found that  when I access the MVC web app first-time, it redirect to login page that request header origin is null. Please advise how to set origin when it redirect.
